# Recent products, best selling products, ... in Anywhere Elementor Pro

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a webpage where I would like to have section that lists best selling or featured/recent woocommerce products. Is it possible to have this using the "AE Posts block" widget in the templates?

Answer (score 0):

use the "Woo – Products Widget" for Elementor instead. This will give you full control on products you want to display. 
i hope this help.

Comment: "Woo - Products Widget" follows default woocommerce template. I want to be able to show my own template for the products in the grid.